# I am getting error Error: [$compile:tplrt] while using directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

In angularJS 1.3.14

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.name = 'world';
  }]);
  //here i created directive of name helloWorld
  app.directive('helloWorld',function(){
    return {
 replace:true,
 restrict:'AE',
 template :'<h3>Hello world<h3/>'
   }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <body ng-controller = "myController">
       <hello-world/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error is :**

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'helloWorld' must have
>   exactly one root element.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick fix**

Root cause(`replace: true`)

1. `<hello-world></hello-world>`
2. change directive template to close `h3` tag properly `template :'<h3>Hello world</h3>'`

**Explanation**

There are two problem in your code.

1. You should close your directive custom element like `<hello-world><hello-world/>`. If you do not close the tag, first occurrence will work fine but after that rest of the thing will not work. [See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yJqRdJsjaMhX93eXnwW3?p=preview).
2. Other thing is your template of directive has wrong `template`

**Directive template**

```
<h3>Hello world<h3/>
```

should be

```
<h3>Hello world</h3>
```

You have template in directive like `<h3>Hello world<h3/>` which has not closing the `h3` tag properly.

So that gets rendered on page like below, which has two `h3` element.

```
<h3>Hello world</h3>
<h3></h3>
```

So the render html has two elements which are individual. So while passing them to `$compile` service to compile the content of template, it is throwing `[$compile:tplrt]` which means your template should have single root element, so the angular will compile that element.

Answer (score 0):

comment the replace: true.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'world';
        }]);

//**here i created directive of name helloWorld**
        app.directive('helloWorld',function(){
            return {
                restrict:'AE',
                //replace:true,
                template :'<h3>Hello world<h3/>'
            };
            });

or 

    //**here i created directive of name helloWorld**
            app.directive('helloWorld',function(){
                return {
                    restrict:'AE',
                    replace:true,
                    template :'<div><h3>Hello world<h3/></div>'
                };
                });
```

Comment: for the replace :  true you need a single root element in the template. Your template does not meet that criteria..  other option is to surround yout template by <div></div>                           restrict:'AE',
    replace:true,
    template :'<div><h3>Hello world<h3/></div>'

Comment: It has `h3` tag as root elemnt. Except `h3` tag is not properly closed

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because in your directive you are using `replace:true` and the template is enclosed in `h3` tag winch is not closed properly (you should close `h3` tag using `</h3>` not `<h3/>`).

You should enclose the template in a root tag properly like `<h3>Hello world</h3>`.

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
>   replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
>   is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
>   templateUrl must be contained within a single html element. For
>   example, `<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p>` instead of simply `blah <em>blah</em> blah`. Otherwise, the replacement operation would result
>   in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple
>   elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in
>   practice.

**[Reference : Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt)**